# How Can I prcoess some data and store it to multiple tables through Spring XD Sink

Tags: java, spring, spring-xd

I am using spring xd to get data from a raw table and process it and then store it to multiple tables.

I got success to store in to one tables.

The problem i am facing is how to store data to mutiple tables using Spring XD sink jdbc.

Currently I am creating stream through following code. It will fetch data from raw table(raw_device_data) and after processing it is storing it to sleep_analysis table.

```
stream create db --definition "source:jdbc --query='select data from raw_device_data where id=330' --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rahar --driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver --username=postgres --password=root --outputType=application/json | customProcessor15 | sink:jdbc --tableName=sleep_analysis --initializeDatabase=true --columns=latency,sleep_duration,sleep_efficiency,total_minutes_in_bed,total_sleep_time,wakefulness --url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/rahar --driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver --username=postgres --password=root"  --deploy
```

I want to store the processed data to multiple tables.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the result to a `topic` named channel. Create two (or more) streams to consume from that topic - see [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#named-channels).

```
foo | bar > topic:result

topic:result > jdbc1

topic:result > jdbc2
```

Comment: I have to insert raw data in to two tables. and one of them having the foreign dependency of other. so how do pass the id of first tables to another.

Comment: In that case you'll need a custom JDBC sink.

Comment: I check this example to create custom sink. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578688/how-to-implement-a-spring-xd-sink

but how i can do insert rows in java method.

Comment: Use a [JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html).